# Amazon Aurora MySQL: Can't you specify number of Replicas on creation time?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I can see that after creating an Aurora MySQL I can then "Add a Reader" to the DB cluster. But isn't there a way to create a specified number of Replicas in the first place?

Comment: No. Not from Console. Use CloudFormation template to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The scenarios that are easiest to understand are a cluster with a single DB instance (e.g. a developer system where availability isn't crucial) and a production cluster (where you want 2 instances at a minimum for high availability). The choice of 1 or 2 instances on initial cluster creation is controlled by the "Multi-AZ" option in the Create Cluster dialog. Selecting Multi-AZ gets you a writer instance and a reader instance. Having >1 reader instance is more for scalability reasons, and involves other considerations (promotion tiers, do all the instances get the same instance class and parameter group, etc.). I presume that bundling all those choices into the console dialog would clutter up the interface and make it easy for people to overprovision by accident.

What I normally do is automate the creation of 3-, 4-, etc. instance clusters using the AWS CLI commands. I create the cluster and the first (writer) instance, wait for the first instance to become available, then create all the reader instances. If you kick off creating all the instances at once, it's a race condition - whichever one finishes first becomes the writer.